# pass token to nswag apiclient in .Netcore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, jwt, nswagstudio

I have generated my `APIclient` Code using `Nswagstudio` as you can see :

```
//----------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     Generated using the NSwag toolchain v13.6.1.0 (NJsonSchema v10.1.21.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v12.0.0.0)) (http://NSwag.org)
// </auto-generated>
//----------------------

#pragma warning disable 108 // Disable "CS0108 '{derivedDto}.ToJson()' hides inherited member '{dtoBase}.ToJson()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended."
#pragma warning disable 114 // Disable "CS0114 '{derivedDto}.RaisePropertyChanged(String)' hides inherited member 'dtoBase.RaisePropertyChanged(String)'. To make the current member override that implementation, add the override keyword. Otherwise add the new keyword."
#pragma warning disable 472 // Disable "CS0472 The result of the expression is always 'false' since a value of type 'Int32' is never equal to 'null' of type 'Int32?'
#pragma warning disable 1573 // Disable "CS1573 Parameter '...' has no matching param tag in the XML comment for ...
#pragma warning disable 1591 // Disable "CS1591 Missing XML comment for publicly visible type or member ..."

namespace MyNamespace
{
    using System = global::System;
    
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NSwag", "13.6.1.0 (NJsonSchema v10.1.21.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v12.0.0.0))")]
    public partial interface IDefault1Client
    {
        /// <returns>Success</returns>
        /// <exception cref="ApiException">A server side error occurred.</exception>
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Jwttoken> CreateTokenAsync();
    
        /// <param name="cancellationToken">A cancellation token that can be used by other objects or threads to receive notice of cancellation.</param>
        /// <returns>Success</returns>
        /// <exception cref="ApiException">A server side error occurred.</exception>
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Jwttoken> CreateTokenAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    
        /// <returns>Success</returns>
        /// <exception cref="ApiException">A server side error occurred.</exception>
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<string>> ReturnListAsync();
    
        /// <param name="cancellationToken">A cancellation token that can be used by other objects or threads to receive notice of cancellation.</param>
        /// <returns>Success</returns>
        /// <exception cref="ApiException">A server side error occurred.</exception>
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<string>> ReturnListAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken);
    
    }
    
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NSwag", "13.6.1.0 (NJsonSchema v10.1.21.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v12.0.0.0))")]
    public partial class Default1Client : IDefault1Client
    {
        private string _baseUrl = "";
        private System.Lazy<Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings> _settings;
    
        public Default1Client(string baseUrl)
        {
            BaseUrl = baseUrl; 
            _settings = new System.Lazy<Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings>(CreateSerializerSettings);
        }
    
        private Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings CreateSerializerSettings()
        {
            var settings = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings();
            UpdateJsonSerializerSettings(settings);
            return settings;
        }
    
        public string BaseUrl 
        {
            get { return _baseUrl; }
            set { _baseUrl = value; }
        }
    
        protected Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings JsonSerializerSettings { get { return _settings.Value; } }
    
        partial void UpdateJsonSerializerSettings(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings settings);
        partial void PrepareRequest(System.Net.Http.HttpClient client, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, string url);
        partial void PrepareRequest(System.Net.Http.HttpClient client, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Text.StringBuilder urlBuilder);
        partial void ProcessResponse(System.Net.Http.HttpClient client, System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response);
    
        /// <returns>Success</returns>
        /// <exception cref="ApiException">A server side error occurred.</exception>
        public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Jwttoken> CreateTokenAsync()
        {
            return CreateTokenAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
        }
    
        /// <param name="cancellationToken">A cancellation token that can be used by other objects or threads to receive notice of cancellation.</param>
        /// <returns>Success</returns>
        /// <exception cref="ApiException">A server side error occurred.</exception>
        public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Jwttoken> CreateTokenAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var urlBuilder_ = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            urlBuilder_.Append(BaseUrl != null ? BaseUrl.TrimEnd('/') : "").Append("/api/Default1/CreateToken");
    
            var client_ = await CreateHttpClientAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            try
            {
                using (var request_ = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage())
                {
                    request_.Method = new System.Net.Http.HttpMethod("GET");
                    request_.Headers.Accept.Add(System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("text/plain"));
    
                    PrepareRequest(client_, request_, urlBuilder_);
                    var url_ = urlBuilder_.ToString();
                    request_.RequestUri = new System.Uri(url_, System.UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                    PrepareRequest(client_, request_, url_);
    
                    var response_ = await client_.SendAsync(request_, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    try
                    {
                        var headers_ = System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary(response_.Headers, h_ => h_.Key, h_ => h_.Value);
                        if (response_.Content != null && response_.Content.Headers != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var item_ in response_.Content.Headers)
                                headers_[item_.Key] = item_.Value;
                        }
    
                        ProcessResponse(client_, response_);
    
                        var status_ = ((int)response_.StatusCode).ToString();
                        if (status_ == "200") 
                        {
                            var objectResponse_ = await ReadObjectResponseAsync<Jwttoken>(response_, headers_).ConfigureAwait(false);
                            return objectResponse_.Object;
                        }
                        else
                        if (status_ != "200" && status_ != "204")
                        {
                            var responseData_ = response_.Content == null ? null : await response_.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); 
                            throw new ApiException("The HTTP status code of the response was not expected (" + (int)response_.StatusCode + ").", (int)response_.StatusCode, responseData_, headers_, null);
                        }
            
                        return default(Jwttoken);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (response_ != null)
                            response_.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (client_ != null)
                    client_.Dispose();
            }
        }
    
        /// <returns>Success</returns>
        /// <exception cref="ApiException">A server side error occurred.</exception>
        public System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<string>> ReturnListAsync()
        {
            return ReturnListAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
        }
    
        /// <param name="cancellationToken">A cancellation token that can be used by other objects or threads to receive notice of cancellation.</param>
        /// <returns>Success</returns>
        /// <exception cref="ApiException">A server side error occurred.</exception>
        public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<string>> ReturnListAsync(System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var urlBuilder_ = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            urlBuilder_.Append(BaseUrl != null ? BaseUrl.TrimEnd('/') : "").Append("/api/Default1/ReturnList");
    
            var client_ = await CreateHttpClientAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            try
            {
                using (var request_ = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage())
                {
                    request_.Method = new System.Net.Http.HttpMethod("GET");
                    request_.Headers.Accept.Add(System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("text/plain"));
    
                    PrepareRequest(client_, request_, urlBuilder_);
                    var url_ = urlBuilder_.ToString();
                    request_.RequestUri = new System.Uri(url_, System.UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                    PrepareRequest(client_, request_, url_);
    
                    var response_ = await client_.SendAsync(request_, System.Net.Http.HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
                    try
                    {
                        var headers_ = System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary(response_.Headers, h_ => h_.Key, h_ => h_.Value);
                        if (response_.Content != null && response_.Content.Headers != null)
                        {
                            foreach (var item_ in response_.Content.Headers)
                                headers_[item_.Key] = item_.Value;
                        }
    
                        ProcessResponse(client_, response_);
    
                        var status_ = ((int)response_.StatusCode).ToString();
                        if (status_ == "200") 
                        {
                            var objectResponse_ = await ReadObjectResponseAsync<System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<string>>(response_, headers_).ConfigureAwait(false);
                            return objectResponse_.Object;
                        }
                        else
                        if (status_ != "200" && status_ != "204")
                        {
                            var responseData_ = response_.Content == null ? null : await response_.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false); 
                            throw new ApiException("The HTTP status code of the response was not expected (" + (int)response_.StatusCode + ").", (int)response_.StatusCode, responseData_, headers_, null);
                        }
            
                        return default(System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<string>);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (response_ != null)
                            response_.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (client_ != null)
                    client_.Dispose();
            }
        }
    
        protected struct ObjectResponseResult<T>
        {
            public ObjectResponseResult(T responseObject, string responseText)
            {
                this.Object = responseObject;
                this.Text = responseText;
            }
    
            public T Object { get; }
    
            public string Text { get; }
        }
    
        public bool ReadResponseAsString { get; set; }
        
        protected virtual async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<ObjectResponseResult<T>> ReadObjectResponseAsync<T>(System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary<string, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>> headers)
        {
            if (response == null || response.Content == null)
            {
                return new ObjectResponseResult<T>(default(T), string.Empty);
            }
        
            if (ReadResponseAsString)
            {
                var responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                try
                {
                    var typedBody = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseText, JsonSerializerSettings);
                    return new ObjectResponseResult<T>(typedBody, responseText);
                }
                catch (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException exception)
                {
                    var message = "Could not deserialize the response body string as " + typeof(T).FullName + ".";
                    throw new ApiException(message, (int)response.StatusCode, responseText, headers, exception);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    using (var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
                    using (var streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream))
                    using (var jsonTextReader = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader(streamReader))
                    {
                        var serializer = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Create(JsonSerializerSettings);
                        var typedBody = serializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonTextReader);
                        return new ObjectResponseResult<T>(typedBody, string.Empty);
                    }
                }
                catch (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonException exception)
                {
                    var message = "Could not deserialize the response body stream as " + typeof(T).FullName + ".";
                    throw new ApiException(message, (int)response.StatusCode, string.Empty, headers, exception);
                }
            }
        }
    
        private string ConvertToString(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            if (value is System.Enum)
            {
                string name = System.Enum.GetName(value.GetType(), value);
                if (name != null)
                {
                    var field = System.Reflection.IntrospectionExtensions.GetTypeInfo(value.GetType()).GetDeclaredField(name);
                    if (field != null)
                    {
                        var attribute = System.Reflection.CustomAttributeExtensions.GetCustomAttribute(field, typeof(System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute)) 
                            as System.Runtime.Serialization.EnumMemberAttribute;
                        if (attribute != null)
                        {
                            return attribute.Value != null ? attribute.Value : name;
                        }
                    }
        
                    return System.Convert.ToString(System.Convert.ChangeType(value, System.Enum.GetUnderlyingType(value.GetType()), cultureInfo));
                }
            }
            else if (value is bool) 
            {
                return System.Convert.ToString(value, cultureInfo).ToLowerInvariant();
            }
            else if (value is byte[])
            {
                return System.Convert.ToBase64String((byte[]) value);
            }
            else if (value != null && value.GetType().IsArray)
            {
                var array = System.Linq.Enumerable.OfType<object>((System.Array) value);
                return string.Join(",", System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(array, o => ConvertToString(o, cultureInfo)));
            }
        
            return System.Convert.ToString(value, cultureInfo);
        }
    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NJsonSchema", "10.1.21.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v12.0.0.0)")]
    public partial class Jwttoken 
    {
        [Newtonsoft.Json.JsonProperty("token", Required = Newtonsoft.Json.Required.Default, NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string Token { get; set; }
    
    
    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NSwag", "13.6.1.0 (NJsonSchema v10.1.21.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v12.0.0.0))")]
    public partial class ApiException : System.Exception
    {
        public int StatusCode { get; private set; }

        public string Response { get; private set; }

        public System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary<string, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>> Headers { get; private set; }

        public ApiException(string message, int statusCode, string response, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary<string, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>> headers, System.Exception innerException) 
            : base(message + "\n\nStatus: " + statusCode + "\nResponse: \n" + response.Substring(0, response.Length >= 512 ? 512 : response.Length), innerException)
        {
            StatusCode = statusCode;
            Response = response; 
            Headers = headers;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format("HTTP Response: \n\n{0}\n\n{1}", Response, base.ToString());
        }
    }

    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCode("NSwag", "13.6.1.0 (NJsonSchema v10.1.21.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v12.0.0.0))")]
    public partial class ApiException<TResult> : ApiException
    {
        public TResult Result { get; private set; }

        public ApiException(string message, int statusCode, string response, System.Collections.Generic.IReadOnlyDictionary<string, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>> headers, TResult result, System.Exception innerException) 
            : base(message, statusCode, response, headers, innerException)
        {
            Result = result;
        }
    }

}
```

So I have added this code to my MVC core endpoint with these configurations

```
  services.AddScoped<IDefault1Client>(provider =>
            {
                return new Default1Client("https://localhost:44381");
            });
```

My apli using JWT as a security pattern.But myproblem is how can I pass my token into httpclient of the above code thatis generated by nswag studio .?

Answer (score 1):

If i correct understand you

You have partial method

```
PrepareRequest
```

You can write header adding in this method

**UPD:**

```
partial void PrepareRequest(IHttpClient client, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, string url)
{
    var (name, value) = GetSecurityHeader();
    
    request.Headers.Add(name, value);
}
```

Comment: in which parts I should add this partial ?

Comment: this partial method was generated to you by nswag in your APIclient file. You should create partial class for client with PrepareRequest and realization that you need

Comment: Yes yo are right but how should i pass my token to this class ?in Startup file ?or in middleware

Comment: you should provide it directly in this method